# Error al ejecutar gem install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

tratando de instalar rails, luego de haber instalado ruby y rubygems, trato de ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

lo que me da como resultado el siguiente error:

```
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

El comando finaliza con error y no se termina de instalar la gema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se debe a ciertas dependencias o librerias de desarrollo no instaladas. En sistemas debian-ubuntu solo hay que ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Previamente tendriamos que haber instalado el paquete develop de ruby:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Luego de esto podremos ejecutar satisfactoriamente el comando de instalación de la  gema de rails:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: No te recomiendo realizar las instalaciones con sudo ya que luego podria ser complicado el manejar varias aplicaciones con distintas versiones de ruby y gemas

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente no te recomiendo realizar la instalación usando

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Ya que esto instalara una version especifica de rails en tu sistema y la hara disponible, el problema futuro podria ser tener que abrir una aplicación en una version distinta de rails o incluso algunas gemas, por lo que se recomienda usar manejadores de versiones como rvm o rbenv

La razón del mensaje de error es que ruby no encuentra algunas librerias necesarias como pre requisitos para rails, esto se debe a que ruby es un lenguaje que por razones de performance prefiere interactuar directamente con las librerias nativas del sistema operativo.

Podrias resolverlo con:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Si vas a usar un manejador de versiones como te recomendé, asegurate de ejecutar este comando antes para que no tengas que instalarlo luego dentro del contexto del manejador de versiones.